# don't re-assign variable reloading script

Tags: javascript, global-variables, reloading

I have a script in JavaScript which is called several times in a html page. I want to know how it's possible to assign values ​​to a variable only the first call of the script.

```
var processingYear = 0;
var recupMonth = 0;
var recupYear = 0;


if(processingMonth == startMonth && processingYear == startYear && recupMonth == 0 && recupYear == 0){
            recupMonth = startMonth;
            recupYear = startYear;
        }
```

Comment: Even the declarations are called again and again?

Comment: You should include the script just once, and use functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand correctly you want to include the same script multiple times in the same HTML page. To prevent the script from overwriting your initializations, you can simply check if the variables have values before redefining them:

Instead of:

```
var x = 2;
```

Do:

```
var x = (x !== undefined) ? x : 2;
```

A shorter version would be `var x = x || 2;`, but that can backfire if your x variable holds a value that is evaluated to false (for example 0) after the script is executed.

Answer (score 3):

```
var processingYear = processingYear || 0;
```

Comment: It should be `var processingYear = processingYear || 0;`

Comment: @Tibos Bitwise OR (`|`) should work too, but only on `Number` types.

Comment: @Der Flatulator `1|2 === 3`. I'm quite sure that's not what you had in mind.

Comment: @Tibos, only with `0`. `n | 0 === n`, or `0` if n is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.count ? count="defined" : count="undefined";
if(count=="undefined"){
  var processingYear = 0;
  var recupMonth = 0;
  var recupYear = 0;
}
```

Just another way to do !